# How to change sprite image when focus input form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onfocus

Basically I have input form

```
<div class="input-area search-input-icon">
<span></span>
<input type="text" value="Enter" class="search-input">
</div>
```

and css for my input

```
.search-input-icon span {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('../img/../img/tek-s24f4d4af1d.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -388px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    display: block;
    top: 25%;
    left: 5%;
}

.search-input:focus{
       border-color:#faa82b;
        .search-in-out-icon {
            span{
                @include tek-sprite(hover-form-search);
            }
        }
    }
```

but whenever focus on input form my span icon is not change why ?

Comment: you might be better with `.search-input-icon span:focus` and changing the `background-position`

Comment: You cannot change the parent element by event of the children. See [There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/6238076)